# Open a file if passed as a parameter, otherwise open main app menu

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am building a desktop application using QML, and I want to make a menu (to load or create new project) and then loading the mainWindow(I am using the `QQmlApplicationEngine` and so an `ApplicationWindow` as root).

But I want to allow to load project directly from project file stored on the disk. So if argc from main is upper than 1, i.e there is second argument and it is the path to the project file, so the application don't load the menu, but directly the mainWindow.

So my question is what is the best way to implement it?
I am now doing it with the loading method of engine, and if statement for the menu or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path of the file you want to download as a context property.

Then in `onCompleted` for `main.qml` you check for a valid path, if there is one - load the file, if not, then load your main menu.

You could probably do it without any C++ too, in QML you can use `Qt.application.arguments[index]` to get direct access to any passed parameters.

```
  Component.onCompleted: {
    var args = Qt.application.arguments
    if (args.length > 1) loadProject(args[1]) // presuming it checks path validity
    else loadMenu()
  }
```